# 2nd block not showing up in D7

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm building a module with several blocks. But only one is showing up in blocks list.
Calendar shows up in block list but could you see why I cant see my 'frontdoor' block ?

```
function businesshours_block_info() {
    $blocks['calendar'] = array (
        'info' => t('Little calendar'),
        'status' => true,
        'visibility' => 1,
        );
    $blocks['frontdoor'] = array (
        'info' => t('The Front Door'),
        'status' => FALSE,
        'visibility' => 0,
        );
    return $blocks;
}
function businesshours_block_view($delta) {
    $block = array();
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'calendar':
            $block['content'] = businesshours_block_contents($delta);
            $block['subject'] = t('toto');
            return $block;
            break;
        case 'frontdoor':
            $block['content'] = businesshours_block_contents($delta);
            $block['subject'] = t('front');
            break;
    }
    return $block;

}
function businesshours_block_contents($delta) {
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'calendar':
            return array('#markup' => '<div style="width:8.2em;margin:auto;">' . _build_calendar() . '</div>');
            break;
        case 'frontdoor':
            return array('#markup' => '<div style="width:8.2em;margin:auto;">' . _build_frontdoor() . '</div>');
            break;
    }
}
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return $block` in `case 'calendar'`

```
function businesshours_block_view($delta) {
$block = array();
switch ($delta) {
    case 'calendar':
        $block['content'] = businesshours_block_contents($delta);
        $block['subject'] = t('toto');
        break;
    case 'frontdoor':
        $block['content'] = businesshours_block_contents($delta);
        $block['subject'] = t('front');
        break;
}
return $block;
}
```

NOTE: Also check your visibility

Possible values are:

> BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED: Show on all pages except listed pages.
> 'pages' lists the paths where the block should not be shown.
>
> BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED: Show only on listed pages. 'pages' lists the
> paths where the block should be shown.
>
> BLOCK_VISIBILITY_PHP: Use
> custom PHP code to determine visibility. 'pages' gives the PHP code to
> use. Most modules do not provide an initial value for 'visibility' or
> 'pages', and any value provided can be modified by a user on the block
> configuration screen.

Comment: Right...that shouldn't be in there.

Comment: It was only a typo. Anyway it couldnt prevent it working. Anyway I did the edit and it still doesnt show up...

Comment: In fact  I understood that block_info is fired only once at module setup. If you edit the code after, no new block will be added. Uninstall required. Also if status is set to True you'll want to assign a it a region... So false is better : it leaves you choose your region in the admin (theme have different regions)

Answer (score 0):

Their is no hook for content in blocks.U cant use $delta in content of block type.
U have to use different functions for each of the block type.

Eg:

```
function businesshours_block_view($delta) {
$block = array();
switch ($delta) {
    case 'calendar':
        $block['content'] = businesshours_block_content1();
        $block['subject'] = t('toto');
        return $block;
        break;
    case 'frontdoor':
        $block['content'] = businesshours_block_content2();
        $block['subject'] = t('front');
        break;
}
return $block;
}

function businesshours_block_content1(){


  return array('#markup' => '<div style="width:8.2em;margin:auto;">' . _build_calendar() . '</div>');  

}
function businesshours_block_content2(){

  return array('#markup' => '<div style="width:8.2em;margin:auto;">' . _build_frontdoor() . '</div>');

 }
```

Comment: In fact I understood that block_info is fired only once at module setup. If you edit the code after, no new block will be added. Uninstall required. Also if status is set to True you'll want to assign a it a region... So false is better : it leaves you choose your region in the admin (theme have different regions). Thx for your help...

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you cannot see the block in the region on your page or in the Manage Blocks administration page. I am assuming you can't see it on your site pages (not the Manage Blocks page).

The reason you would not see `frontdoors` block on your site is that you have set status to FALSE. Unless you move the block to one of the theme's regions, you will not see this block.